# Flutter the getter 'amount' isn't defined for the class

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to redirect user on details payment screen when payment is initiated and change state automatically when user confirm payment.

Detail screen :

```
child: FutureBuilder<Deposit?>(
  future: AuthService.addDeposit(amount, product, phone, authProvider.token!),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<Deposit?> snapshot){
    if(snapshot.hasData){
      return _snapshotHasData(snapshot.data!);
    }else if(snapshot.hasError){
      return Text('${snapshot.error}');
    }
    return const LinearProgressIndicator();
  },
)
```

Service:

```
static Future<Deposit?> addDeposit(String amount, String product, String phone, String token) async {
  assert(token.isNotEmpty);
  Response<String> response = await _dio.post(
    'url',
    data: <String, String>{
      'amount': amount,
      'product': product,
      'phone': phone,
    
    },
  );
  if(response.statusCode != 200){
    throw Exception(response.statusMessage);
  }
  return Deposit.fromJson(jsonDecode(response.data ?? ''));
}
```

I put just one parameter for show you the widget

```
Widget _snapshotHasData(Deposit data){
    return Text(data.amount);
  }
```

Comment: You must add more information. Provide the code where you get the error. Maybe this method: `_snapshotHasData()` ?

Comment: I obtain the error in future: AuthService.addDeposit(amoun, product, ...)

Comment: You don't have a getter there.

Comment: Where do you define and use "amount" in the "DetailScreen" ?